# How to detect the element i clicked on from an array

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make this project where i have a bunch of photos. I want to make it so that whenever i hover on a photo an < i > element displays as block ( default it is none ). I can't figure out how to make it.. everything i used made it so that all the i elements displayed.
This is the javaScript code.

```
JavaScript

var poza = document.querySelectorAll(".poza");
var plus = document.querySelectorAll(".plus");
poza.forEach(function (e) {
    e.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < plus.length; i++)
            plus[i].style.display = "block"
    })
    e.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < plus.length; i++)
            plus[i].style.display = "none"
    })
})
```

```
HTML

            <div class="row poze">
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <img class="poza" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534438327276-14e5300c3a48?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                    <i class="plus fas fa-plus-square"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <img class="poza" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1571902943202-507ec2618e8f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                    <i class="plus fas fa-plus-square"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <img class="poza" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1540497077202-7c8a3999166f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                    <i class="plus fas fa-plus-square"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <img class="poza" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534258936925-c58bed479fcb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                    <i class="plus fas fa-plus-square"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <img class="poza" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517343985841-f8b2d66e010b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                    <i class="plus fas fa-plus-square"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <img class="poza" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1561140895-9d144461935e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
                    <i class="plus fas fa-plus-square"></i>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### You can acheive this using self-executing function:

```js
var poza = document.querySelectorAll(".poza");
var plus = document.querySelectorAll(".plus");

poza.forEach(function (e, i) {
    e.addEventListener("mouseover", (function (newI) {
        return function() {
            plus[newI].style.display = "block"
        }
    })(i))
    e.addEventListener("mouseout", (function (newI) {
        return function() {
            plus[newI].style.display = "none"
        }
    })(i))
})
```

Comment: You have to remove the "newI" parameter of the innermost functions, otherwise the "newI" variable will hold the event object, not the index "i". However, nice way of using closures.

Answer (score 1):

The simple trick you can do is on mouse enter event add a class say hover-effect in each element in an array of poza elements. Then in css use the following rule

```
i {
  display: none;
}

.hover-effect+i {
 display: 'block';        
}
```

On mouse leave remove the class. This approach will be neat and clean.

(see documentation on + selector)

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from the `addEventListener` as `event.target`, one possible solution should be like:

```js
poza.forEach(function (e) {
    e.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
       event.target.style.display = "block"
    })
    e.addEventListener("mouseout", function (event) {
       event.target.style.display = "none"
    })
})
```

See if it helps ;D